# Trying to INSERT a trim'd value in SQL 2012 but it is ignoring the trim

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012

I basically created the inserts in excel because it was the fastest way, copying and pasting it then resulted in this:

```
INSERT INTO MyCatFantasies values       (RTRIM(LTRIM('  boots   ')),RTRIM(LTRIM('   fluff mcgruff                                                                                       ')))
```

The weird spacing is because of the way I copied it from excel. I figured whacking a couple of trims around the values would insert them into the database without spaces before or after, however after doing the insert, I found that it ignored the TRIM commands and the values were padded with the original whitespace.

Is there an explanation for this behaviour / what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces not tabs?

Comment: Could be tabs, yes. Do tabs not get affected by RTRIM?

Comment: AFAIK whitespace char(32) in ASCII..tabs are char(9) and therefore aren't affected by TRIM.Try to replace the tabs with '' and test it out

Comment: I've checked, it's tabs, but I can't do a replace because separating the words fluff mcgruff is also a tab. Any ideas?

Comment: Would going back to the source to remove tabs be too tedious?

Comment: Do your actual fields have more tabs than your normal fields?If so you could count the LEN and REPLACE

Comment: I copied the inserts into notepad, then into word, then find + replaced tab with space, then relied on trim to work correctly. All is good now! I'll delete this question soon, since it's not very useful.

Comment: Hope I helped you in a small way :)